# Date format in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have birth date data stored in Mysql table as below:

```
id firstname middlename lastname   birth
---------------------------------------------
 1 Harry     Chandra    Sihombing  1999-12-14
 2 Janice    Mona       Sihombing  2010-04-20
 .  ...      ...        ...        ...
```

How can I create a search function to collect data from the table and restrict the output to rows `"where age > 25"` (and/or other function using `">"` (greater) `"="` (equal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this with [DATE_SUB](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp)

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 25 YEAR) > birth
```

in php:

```
$age = (int)$_POST['age'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL $age YEAR) > birth";
```

Comment: Thanks, your script doing right. but i want using number interval form variable passing by field search.

Comment: the script become:
DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL $search YEAR) < birth 

I'm get this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Note: $search are value submitted from input text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

```
SELECT NOW(),
    DATE(NOW()),
    DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 YEAR),
    DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 YEAR))
```

... renders something like:

```
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| NOW()               | DATE(NOW()) | DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 YEAR) | DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 YEAR)) |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| 2019-10-29 10:27:52 | 2019-10-29  | 1994-10-29 10:27:52               | 1994-10-29                              |
+---------------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3fb9a3993df773935b50b1ffd5d77a5)).